# Can the CMOS 4014b be used as a SIPO shift register?

Tags: cmos, shift-register

I'm currently working on a school project that requires the use of an 8-bit shift register. I collected the components for the project on the last day of school rather hurriedly, and I picked the first 8-bit shift register that I found, which was the CMOS 4014B IC. I'm now trying to wire it up, and I need it to be a SIPO shift register. I can find almost no resources for the chip's operation. The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4014b.pdf) suggests that the ABCDEFGH pins are all parallel input pins; however the chip also has a serial input pin and a P/S control pin. I don't fully understand what the datasheet says about the P/S pin but it sounds to me that it enables serial inputs to the chip. Can I use it as a SIPO shift register? If so, which pins are used for the parallel outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no parallel outputs on this chip.

[image]

As you can see from the truth table below, when Parallel/Serial in is low a rising clock edge shifts data in from the serial input. When it is high, a rising clock edge loads from the parallel inputs. The only way you can get data out is from Q8, Q7 or Q6.